# Getting the 'name' attribute of a form in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

How can I get the 'name' attribute of a form in Laravel framework?

Comment: have you looked at Laravel documentation, for working with forms ?

Comment: There are multiple ways to target a form using JavaScript/jQuery to retrieve it's `name` attribute. Regardless, this is a JavaScript question and has very little to do with Laravel.

Comment: You mean when it's been submitted to be handled by a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you submit data field "name" with value "test".

You can call the `Input::get()` function like so:

```
$fields = Input::get();
```

This will give you an array like so:

```
Array ( [name] => test )
```

now you can run a foreach loop to get the names like so:

```
foreach($fields as $name => $value)
{
    echo $name; //it will give you "name"
}
```

also do not forget `use Input;`

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I don't want to get an input, I want to get the name of the form. I am looking for this: <form name="getThisValueHere"></form>

Comment: You could add a hidden input with the form-name then it will be submitted along with the form. Forms don't POST their name attribute like the other inputs.